# Alphabetize lines in file then remove duplicate lines

Tags: php, string, file, sorting, alphabetical

I am trying to sort a long text file (thousands of lines) alphabetically and then remove any duplicate lines.

Each line only contains one word and I need each of those words, one word lines, to be in alphabetically order. Then I want any duplicate lines to be removed and the result ( the sorted and unique list ) to be written to a new text file with one word one each line.

How can I do this in PHP?

Right now, I'm thinking about how to do this and I would read in the file with `file()` and then make an array with the elements being each line. Then I would sort the array alphabetically, use `array_unique()` to remove duplicates and then write each element to a new line in a new text file.

The issue I am having trouble with in that implementation is the alphabetical sorting.

If you can help me with my implementation, then please do so.

or

If you have a better way of doing what I am trying to do, then please share!

Comment: Is [sort](http://in3.php.net/sort) not working?

Answer (score 1):

As far as the sort goes, I would probably use a natcasesort:  [natcasesort](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php)

The rest is pretty trivial and you should be able to implement it as you see fit.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is not very efficient, you can start with this:

```
$lines = file('filename.txt');
$lines = array_walk($lines, 'trim'); // Remove line-breaks.
$sorted_lines = sort(array_unique($lines));
```

Comment: only change I would make would be to change `file('filename.txt')` to `file('filename.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)` and nix the array_walk.

Comment: How do I write `$sorted_lines` to a new file though? So that each element is on a new line?

Comment: I am trying to write `$sorted_lines` to a new file, but all I am getting is a blank text file. Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/x4P1SkCK

Comment: You can use `file_put_contents`. Quite simply: `file_put_contents('out_file.txt', implode("\n", $sorted_lines));`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that yourself is to implement a [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

The wiki page is quite good enough to make it but I'll make a quick resume for you.

Let's say that you want to sort 5 words

```
Bword
Aword
Cword
Eword
Dword
```

You can sort easily 2 words between each other with [strcmp()](http://php.net/strcmp)

The thing is, how to sort everything ?

You'll need to compare each pair of words from the first to the last, and change their position depending on theit alphabetical order.

the first pair would be

```
Bword
Aword
```

And will become

```
Aword
Bword
```

you then need to move from one word and pairing

```
Bword with
Cword
```

if it's not the good order you swap them, if not, you don't.

By doing that once you'll put the last alphabetical word to the end of the array.
You then just have to repeat that a number of times equal to the number of words you have.

That should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I'd call bash commands from PHP for this.
Provided your code is on Linux with exec allowed in PHP configuration:

```
exec("sort " . $pathToOriginalFile . " | uniq > " . $pathToSortedUniqueFile);
```

It does however create new output file, but in my case it was by far the fastest and most elegant solution as I needed to perform this on a file with over 10 million lines, and it took server only 3-5 seconds to complete.

To keep it in the same file you can do this:

```
exec("sort " . $pathToOriginalFile . " | uniq > " . $pathToSortedUniqueFile);
exec("rm " . $pathToOriginalFile);
exec("mv " . $pathToSortedUniqueFile . " " . $pathToOriginalFile);
```

Hope it helps